# Sonarqube Scanner and Maven Tycho: NullPointerException at DefaultProjectArtifactsCache$CacheKey.<init>

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

Adding the project https://github.com/PalladioSimulator/Palladio-Analyzer-SimuLizar to Sonarqube Community EditionVersion 8.2 (build 32929) running in a docker container with the command:

```
mvn sonar:sonar \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=<key> \
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
  -Dsonar.login=<token>
```

creates the following error:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] parent 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT .............................. FAILURE [  1.203 s]
[INFO] bundles 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ............................. SUCCESS [  0.101 s]
[INFO] Palladio Runtime Monitoring Model 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ... SUCCESS [  4.787 s]
[INFO] Simulizarmeasuringpoint Model 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ....... SUCCESS [  1.124 s]
[INFO] ReconfigurationRule Model 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ........... SUCCESS [  1.776 s]
[INFO] PCM Simulizar Core: PCM Interpreter with self-* features 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  4.186 s]
[INFO] QVT-o Reconfiguration Engine 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ........ SUCCESS [  1.919 s]
[INFO] Palladio Simulizar UI Plugin 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ........ SUCCESS [  1.592 s]
[INFO] Actions Model 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ....................... SUCCESS [  3.539 s]
[INFO] Actions Edit Support 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ................ SUCCESS [  1.867 s]
[INFO] Actions Editor 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ...................... SUCCESS [  4.108 s]
[INFO] Repository 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT .......................... SUCCESS [  1.155 s]
[INFO] Aggregation 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ......................... SUCCESS [  1.274 s]
[INFO] Simulizarmeasuringpoint Edit Support 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT  SUCCESS [  0.627 s]
[INFO] ReconfigurationWithConfidence 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ....... SUCCESS [  1.538 s]
[INFO] org.palladiosimulator.simulizar.events 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  1.459 s]
[INFO] MeasuringPointProfile 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ............... SUCCESS [  0.253 s]
[INFO] Create 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT .............................. SUCCESS [  1.063 s]
[INFO] Feedthrough Support for SimuLizar PRM Measurements 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  1.188 s]
[INFO] Simulizar Monitor Repository Map Implementation 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  1.434 s]
[INFO] Henshin Reconfiguration Engine 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ...... SUCCESS [  2.184 s]
[INFO] HenshinReconfiguration Model 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ........ SUCCESS [  0.794 s]
[INFO] ReconfigurationRule Edit Support 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT .... SUCCESS [  0.882 s]
[INFO] HenshinReconfiguration Edit Support 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT . SUCCESS [  0.733 s]
[INFO] Qvtoreconfiguration Model 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ........... SUCCESS [  0.591 s]
[INFO] Qvtoreconfiguration Edit Support 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT .... SUCCESS [  0.676 s]
[INFO] Storydiagram Reconfiguration Engine 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT . SUCCESS [  1.483 s]
[INFO] Storydiagram Model 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT .................. SUCCESS [  0.754 s]
[INFO] Storydiagram Edit Support 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ........... SUCCESS [  0.694 s]
[INFO] ReconfigurationRule Editor 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT .......... SUCCESS [  1.080 s]
[INFO] Palladio Runtime Monitoring Edit Support 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  0.542 s]
[INFO] Simulizar Sliding Window Implementation 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  1.281 s]
[INFO] Custom_Navigator 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT .................... SUCCESS [  0.548 s]
[INFO] Load Balancer 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ....................... SUCCESS [  0.608 s]
[INFO] Palladio Simulizar Utilization Analysis Extension 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  1.948 s]
[INFO] features 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ............................ SUCCESS [  0.101 s]
[INFO] Palladio Component Model - Analyzer: SimuLizar - Henshin Reconfiguations 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  0.452 s]
[INFO] Palladio Component Model - Analyzer: SimuLizar - QVT Operational Reconfiguations 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  0.244 s]
[INFO] Palladio Component Model - Analyzer: SimuLizar - Story Diagram Reconfiguations 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  0.275 s]
[INFO] Palladio Component Model - Analyzer: SimuLizar 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  0.728 s]
[INFO] Palladio Component Model - Analyzer: SimuLizar - Monitor Repository Map Implementation 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [  0.484 s]
[INFO] tests 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ............................... SUCCESS [  0.183 s]
[INFO] Tests 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ............................... SUCCESS [  1.070 s]
[INFO] Simulizar Sliding Window Tests 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ...... SUCCESS [  1.389 s]
[INFO] SimuLizar Tests 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT ..................... SUCCESS [  1.333 s]
[INFO] releng 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT .............................. SUCCESS [  0.158 s]
[INFO] org.palladiosimulator.simulizar.updatesite 4.2.0-SNAPSHOT SUCCESS [ 21.261 s]
[INFO] target-platform-merged-temporary 1.0.0 ............. SUCCESS [  0.001 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:03 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-20T14:08:45+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.DefaultProjectArtifactsCache$CacheKey.<init> (DefaultProjectArtifactsCache.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.DefaultProjectArtifactsCache.createKey (DefaultProjectArtifactsCache.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:265)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

I've tried Maven 3.6.3, 3.6.2, 3.6.1, 3.6.0 and 3.5.4.

A small test project https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests and the failing parent project https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests can be loaded into Sonarqube.

Comment: It looks like a bug in maven